# Issue on Wordpress BrandooIIS Azure Search not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search, full-text-search

Made a site on Azure but it’s under Brandoo WordPress. Running on SQL and IIS. My problem now is that my search box that was working properly on development is currently not functioning after using it on Azure. Do I need to add anything on my web.config? Would really be glad on your input.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
<ul id="search-result">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <li class="sr-<?php echo get_post_type( $post->ID ); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php } else { ?>

<ul id="search-result">
  <li class="nothing-here"><?php _e( "Sorry, no posts were found.", "framework" ); ?></li>
</ul>
```